# What is wrong with this "proof"? $1$ is always an eigenvalue for $I + A$ ($A$ is nilpotent)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fake-proofs

> Consider the nilpotent matrix $A$ ($A^k = 0$ for some positive $k$).
>   It is well known that the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$.
>
> Then suppose $\lambda$ is any eigenvalue of $I + A$ such that 
>   $(I + A) \mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$ where ($\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$).
>
> Then $I \mathbf{v} + A \mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v} \implies 
>  \mathbf{v} + A \mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v} \implies A \mathbf{v} =
> (\lambda - 1) \mathbf{v}$
>
> We know that $\lambda - 1 = 0$ because the only eigenvalue of a
>   nilpotent matrix is $0$. Therefore $\lambda = 1$

This "proof" seems to indicate that $1$ is always an eigenvalue for the sum of the identity matrix with any nilpotent matrix, but I believe I have a counterexample that disproves this.

I believe my error was in assuming that $I + A$ *has* eigenvalues -- but I do not know how I could prove/disprove this.

If someone could help me see where I've gone wrong I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I'll edit the question. But the question still stands. Is this correct?

Comment: No, you start out with $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $I+A$, then after the block, you change $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue for $A$.

Comment: What you have found is an eigenvalue of $I+A$. *smh*

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $I + A$, but then it comes down to the fact that $A \mathbf{v} = (\lambda - 1) \mathbf{v}$. This would imply that $\lambda - 1$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ but that must be zero.

Comment: @OpenBall That's what I was hoping for ...

Comment: You state "This "proof" seems to indicate that $1$ is always an eigenvalue for nilpotent matrices, but I have found counterexamples to show this is in fact false."  But it seems here that you're saying that $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, which it is not.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Whoops, another typo. Maybe I should have proof read this more. I meant to say "This seems to indicate 1 is always an eigenvalue for the sum of the identity with any nilpotent matrix".

Comment: Perhaps you can give your counterexample, because $1$ should be an eigenvalue of $I+A$.

Comment: Note also that *all* square matrices have eigenvalues, they come from roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for the tips. You're right, my counterexample was completely bogus on further inspection. By the way, doesn't the existence of eigenvalues depend on the closure of the field?

Comment: Yes, you can't write down the eigenvalues unless you go to a sufficient extension of the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have proven that if $A$ is nilpotent, then the eigenvalue of $A+I$ (**NOT** the eigenvalues of $A$) is equal to $1$. There's nothing wrong with the proof.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I believe I somehow forgot how eigenvectors work. My "counterexample" was poorly constructed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate argument (assuming the base field is algebraically closed):

- For a nilpotent matrix with $A^k=0$, all eigenvalues are $0$.

  Proof:  Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue for $A$ and $v\not=0$ an eigenvector for $\lambda$.  Then
  $$
  0=0v=A^kv=\lambda^kv
  $$
  Since $v\not=0$, it must be that $\lambda^k=0$ so that $\lambda=0$
- $1$ is an eigenvalue for $I+A$.  Let $v$ be an eigenvector for $A$.

  Proof: We know that all eigenvalues for $A$ are $0$, so $Av=0$.  Therefore,
  $$
  (I+A)v=Iv+Av=v+0=v.
  $$
  Hence, $1$ is the eigenvalue for $v$ in $I+A$.
- You can prove more, every eigenvalue of $I+A$ is $1$.

  Proof: Suppose that $\mu$ is an eigenvalue for $I+A$ and $w$ the corresponding eigenvector.  Then
  $$
  Aw=((I+A)-I)w=(I+A)w-Iw=\mu w-w=(\mu-1)w.
  $$
  Therefore, $w$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $\mu-1$.  Since the only eigenvalues for $A$ are $0$, $\mu=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda$ is  an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$  then $p(\lambda)$ is eigenvalue of a polynomial $p(A)$.
In this case we have polynomial $p(A)=A+I$ so in this case the eigenvalues of $A$ (all zeros) should be shifted by $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is right.

> If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for the matrix $A$, then, for every scalar $\alpha$, $\lambda+\alpha$ is an eigenvalue for $A+\alpha I$.

Indeed, if $v\ne0$ and $Av=\lambda v$, then
$$
(A+\alpha I)v=Av+\alpha v=\lambda v+\alpha v=(\lambda+\alpha)v
$$

Now you can apply this to show that if $A$ has only the eigenvalue $0$, then $A+I$ has only the eigenvalue $1$. Conversely, if $A+I$ has only the eigenvalue $1$, then $A=(A+I)-I$ has only the eigenvalue $1-1=0$.

This doesn't depend on the field of scalars. However a real matrix is nilpotent if and only if its only eigenvalue *over the complex numbers* is $0$. As an example, the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has $0$ as its only real eigenvalue, but is not nilpotent.